# Sort Data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that records all the data in the worksheet named 'All responses' and another one in the worksheet named 'Leaderboard report' where it filters unique values in column A (NAME) and adds the value of its corresponding columns (C, D, E, F, G, H).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJzRe.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDNU3.png)

In the Leaderboard report, there is a column called 'Total' that sums all the values from column C-H.

and I have these formulas from A2 - I2, respectively, to sum the values of the unique names.

```
=unique(tocol('All responses'!C2:C,1))
=unique(tocol('All responses'!D2:D,1))
=map($A2:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!F:F))))
=map($A2:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!H:H))))
=map($A2:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!I:I))))
=map($A2:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!J:J))))
=map($A2:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!L:L))))
=map($A2:$A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!N:N))))
=IF(A2="",,SUM(C2:H2))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rL8KDZcYXNv-eJTiUW0EtAqTsrpHxn0vk6aitN0t02w/edit#gid=898926167

How do I sort the data on Leaderboard report worksheet using the results in the TOTAL as a reference in descending order? (given the formulas that I already setup in the worksheet)

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this single formula instead:*

```js
=let(Σ,query('All responses'!C2:N,"Select Col1,Col2,sum(Col4),sum(Col6),sum(Col7),sum(Col8),sum(Col10),sum(Col12) where Col1<>'' group by Col1,Col2"),
     sort(byrow(chooserows(Σ,sequence(rows(Σ)-1,1,2)),lambda(Λ,hstack(Λ,sum(choosecols(Λ,sequence(6,1,3)))))),9,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Although, I meant to sort the results in descending order (my bad for not checking). Which part of the formula should I change to sort it in a descending order?

Comment: Change the `1` at the ending to `0`

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, I want to add another criteria on the same formula, which is the sum of the corresponding column values per unique name **per number of week.** Assuming the formula, one of the results should be for Angelica Test, 3, 1, 24, 49, 2, 2, and the total of 81, respectively for week 1. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use your existing formulas with `let` as follows.

```js
=let(names,unique(tocol('All responses'!C2:C,3))
    ,emails,unique(tocol('All responses'!D2:D,3))
    ,data,hstack(
     map(names,lambda(Σ,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!F:F)))
    ,map(names,lambda(Σ,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!H:H)))
    ,map(names,lambda(Σ,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!I:I)))
    ,map(names,lambda(Σ,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!J:J)))
    ,map(names,lambda(Σ,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!L:L)))
    ,map(names,lambda(Σ,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!N:N))))
    ,unsorted,hstack(names,emails,data,byrow(data,lambda(r,sum(r))))
    ,sort(unsorted,columns(unsorted),true))
```

(You could keep all the `if(Σ="",,` if you wish, although unnecessary.)

This should preserve all the formatting in the previous cells. However, it is not the most computationally efficient method because each additional `sumif` call repeats the same comparisons, even though it sums a different column.

[image]